# Detecting Hitbox Collisions (Rectangle)

Tags: xna, c#, 2d, xna-4.0

So I have some Hitboxes set up on 2 classes, HealthPickup and Player.

```
public static Rectangle Hitbox;

public override void Initialize()
{
    Hitbox = new Rectangle(Pos.X, Pos.Y, 32, 32);
}
```

That's just general code, there are other things in the classes too. So what I want to know is why this doesn't work:

```
// This is in the HealthPickup class' Update function.
if (Hitbox.Intersects(Player.Hitbox))
{
    Console.Beep();
}
```

Doesn't work if I put it in the main update function either. Am I missing something?

Comment: So, in your whole game, there is only ever a single player and a single health pickup? The fact that the hitbox is a public field would be repulsive enough without it being static as well.

Comment: Excuse me @Magus, this is a test project so yes. There is only one player and one health pickup. And the hitbox is a public field because I want to access it from another class. And it's static because why the hell not. If you're going to comment on my questions, at least contribute something.

Comment: Passing bad practice off as test code is setting yourself up to find some in your code when you try to do things seriously. I mention the fact that they're static because that could have been directly related to your problem if you'd tried changing the coordinates of more than one object. You can be offended by suggestions to follow good practice, or you can follow them. They tend to have good reasoning behind them, and if you don't know enough to know what it is, it's probably beneficial. Not always, but generally.

Comment: @Magus I appreciate you trying to help me write better code but please note I am a novice and I'm not even sure what `static` does. I just put it on everything so there's no errors. And your first comment wasn't suggesting anything, you were only criticising (which I now realise was an attempt at being constructive)

Comment: You should probably do a bit of study, then. C# isn't as hard as some languages, but that doesn't mean it's easy. Most tutorials should explain fairly early on how to avoid static correctly. What it does is make the object in question exist on the level of the class, rather than an object, so you can only ever have one hitbox across any number of players/health pickups. If you'd known that, my first comment would perhaps have made more sense. I do not suggest jumping into programming a game before knowing a language's basic keywords. You will get frustrated.

Comment: I see now, so my two hitboxes were pretty much saying "There's only room for one of us in this town (namespace)!" So only use static for eg Global Variables?

Comment: If they're on different classes, you don't have that problem. It's very much on a class basis, rather than namespace. Static tends to refer to things that are on the level of the concept of the type, eg: Int32.Max. 2 and 3 don't have a maximum, but the idea of an integer does. So yes, global variables are very much like statics, but not quite. You should avoid them whenever possible, and when you allow them, avoid letting them change. Your code will be far more logical as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely the hitboxes are never colliding.

It's not clear how you're creating the player hitbox, but if it's the same way, they'll never collide. You're creating a rectangle based off the position your object starts at. You should create a hitbox on the fly, based on the current position of the object at the time of the collision check. This ensures your hitboxes are actually where you think they are in the world, and can correctly detect when an intersection happens.

Comment: So what you're saying is my hitboxes don't move with the sprites? They just stay. So I should keep recreating my hitboxes over my sprites in my Update function?

Comment: Yes, you can recreate it every iteration of the Update function, or you can only create them when they're needed. Test it out, see which method works for you.

Comment: I have tried to use this:
`Hitbox = new Rectangle(Pos.X, Pos.Y, 32, 32);`
in my `Update()` in my `HealthPickup.cs` but it still doesn't run the `Beep()`. No idea how to make this work.

Comment: What about the player hitbox? I hope you're not using the same class since you've set Hitbox to a static variable. Also, I'd suggest using the debugger instead of relying on the beep. Attach a break point to the line where you do the intersection test. See what the hitboxes look like and ensure they're getting updated.

Comment: I've managed to do a bit of hardcoding and using the console to find out about what my hitboxes are actually doing. Turns out they were both at x0 y0 but not beeping. So I used the main `Update()` to do some temporary code to update the position of the hitbox according to the player and I got some results. Now I need to figure out how to put this into the `Player` class because my `Player` class' `Update()` doesn't seem to be updating.

Answer (score 1):

What I would to is set a key to show the hit box. I tend to use F1 and that way when I hit the F1 key all my hit boxes show up as red. In order to get that to work you would create a 1x1 blank texture and :

In LoadContent:

```
content.Load<Texture2D>(@"1x1");//or replace 1x1 with where you put the image
```

In Update:

```
KeyboardState keyst=Keyboard.GetState();

If (keyst.IsKeyDown(Keys.F1))
{

    drawHitbox(spritebatch);

}
```

new Draw Function:

```
void drawHitbox(SpriteBatch spriteB)
{

    spriteB.Begin();

    spriteB.draw(1x1Tex,HitboxRect,Color.Red);//NOTE you might need multiple calls to draw depending on how your code is set up.

    spriteB.End();

}
```

This way you can tell where your hit boxes are and if they are actually colliding / moving as long as you hold down the F1 key.